# Finding the longest gap between multiple intervals

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, logic

Imagine you have a variable $n denoting a number of partitions on a timeline, and a variable length array of intervals:

```
$n = 10;
$intervals = [
  [1, 2],
  [2, 2],
  [5, 6],
  [8, 10],
];
```

The problem is to find the largest gap between these intervals on the timeline. For the above question, we have two gaps of lengths 2 and 1, so the answer should be 2. To better visualize it:

[image: intervals visualization]

My straight forward approach is not efficient...

1. Initialize an empty timeline array of length $n with each element set to 'E' as in empty.
2. Foreach loop over each interval and create another for loop from interval start to interval finish and set those elements in the timeline array to 'T' as in taken.
3. Loop over the timeline array and initiate a $counter that increments with each consecutive 'E' characters, then save its value to a variable $max if it is greater than the previous.

What improvements can I do?

Please note:

- Intervals are always sorted in respect to their start positions.
- Intervals don't have to start from the beginning of the timeline nor do they have to end at the timeline's end as well. So, there might be a gap before the first interval and a gap after the last interval.
- Intervals can overlap. So simply calculating the next interval's start minus this interval's finish will not work... Consider this example: [1,5] [2,4] [6,10] [6,8]

Comment: are your `$intervals` always in sorted order?

Comment: @NickParsons thanks, yes I meant 2 and 1. Intervals are always sorted by their start position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$n = 10;
$intervals = [
  [1, 2],
  [2, 2],
  [5, 6],
  [8, 10]
];

$non_overlapping = [];
$start = -1;
$end = -1;

foreach($intervals as $index => $interval){
    if($start == -1) $start = $interval[0];
    if($end == -1) $end = $interval[1];

    if($index == 0) continue; // since it's first index

    if($interval[0] >= $end){
        $non_overlapping[] = [$start,$end];
        $start = $interval[0];
        $end = $interval[1];
    }else{
        $end = max($end,$interval[1]);
    }
}

$non_overlapping[] = [$start,$end];
$maximum_gap = 0;
$prev_end = 0;

foreach($non_overlapping as $index => $interval){
    $maximum_gap = max($maximum_gap,$interval[0] - $prev_end - 1);
    $prev_end = $interval[1];
}

$maximum_gap = max($maximum_gap,$n - $prev_end);

echo $maximum_gap;
```

- Since your intervals are sorted according to start time, we make a new array of non overlapping intervals.
- Now, we just subtract new start time with previous end time and at last also, last end time with `$n` itself and find the maximum gap.

Comment: @sandrows glad to help :)

Comment: For $n=100 with 40 intervals, the execution time is ~ 68 us... Selecting yours as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Solution :-**

```
$intervals = [
    [1,2],
    [2,2],
    [5,6],
    [8,10]
];
$rr = [];
foreach($intervals as $v){
    $rr[] = range($v[0],$v[1]);
}
$n = 10;
$range      = range(1,$n);
$diff =     array_diff($range,array_values(array_unique(array_merge(...$rr))));
$r = groupConsecutive($diff);

$max = 0;
if (count($r)) {
    foreach ($r as $gap) {
        $length = 1;
        if (is_array($gap)) $length = count($gap);
        if ($max < $length) $max = $length;
    }
}

echo $max;

function  groupConsecutive($array) {
   $ret  = array();
   $temp = array();
   foreach($array as $val) {
      if(next($array) == ($val + 1))
         $temp[] = $val;
      else
         if(count($temp) > 0) {
            $temp[] = $val;
            $ret[]  = $temp;
            $temp   = array();
         }
         else
            $ret[] = $val;
   }
   return $ret;
}
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/7G4UF)

Comment: This is to find the longest interval, isn't it?

Comment: I want to find the longest gap not the longest interval.

Comment: @sandrows this is what it does the last element array have `8,10` , which has longest gap

Comment: The longest gap means the free blocks between intervals, not the interval duration. Kindly check the image I posted for better visualization.

Comment: Nice approach @RakeshJakhar, however, it fails for intervals spanning over 3 blocks (consider [2,4] [5,8] [9,10]), and if you have two gaps with more than 1 free block, the counter keeps incrementing (consider [1,1] [5,6] [9,10]).

Comment: @sandrows answer has been updated, can you please check now

Comment: thank you I think it works, I have added an edit to actually select the longest gap from your return array, instead of just outputting the gaps.

Comment: @sandrows you can accept the answer and upvote if this resolves your problem.

Comment: For $n=100 with 40 intervals, the execution time is ~ 129 us... up voting :)

Answer (score 0):

If the partitions are sorted (like in your example). You can iterate over the partitions and create a new array containing:

- The original postion of the interval in the first array
- The distance of the first element of the partition and the last element of the previous partition.

With that you will have a list of gaps between partitions. Then you simply sort those gaps and take the last one.

But as I've said this is assuming that your partitions are *sorted*.

There an example then you sort `$gaps` by second element of the value and take the last one.

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

$n = 10;
$intervals = [
  [1, 2],
  [2, 2],
  [5, 6],
  [8, 10],
];

$gaps = array();

$prev_range_max = 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($intervals); $i++) {
    $gaps[] = Array($i, $intervals[$i][0] - $prev_range_max);
    $prev_range_max = $intervals[$i][1];
}
```

Comment: Good approach that takes into consideration if there is a gap before the first interval, however, it does not account for the gap after the last interval.

Comment: It will not work with overlapping intervals, consider these [1,5] [2,4] [6,10] [6,8]. It also calculates the interval's end as gap, so you need to subtract 1 in each calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I am describing an approach that will be much efficient-

1. If the intervals are unsorted according to the start time-
   First sort the array of intervals based on the start time.
   Worst case complexity O(nlogn). if its sorted then we don't have to do anything.
2. Iterate through the sorted interval array from the second element  and each iteration if the start time is greater than the end time of last interval - calculate the difference .
3. Find out the max difference comparing the difference in each iteration.

   Complexity-
   Unsorted Array- O(nlogn)+ O(n)
   Sorted Array- O(n).

pseudo code--

[image]

example--

[image]

Comment: This will not work for overlapping intervals, consider [1,5] [2,4] [6,10] [6,8] it should output 0, however, with this approach it will output 1. Also you need to consider gaps at start/end of the timeline; before the first interval's start and after the last interval's end.

Comment: hi i've given a pseudo code and a simulation plz check it .

Comment: In your example you returned maxgap = 1. However, if you visualize it, it should be zero.

Comment: i've made a mistake in the test case simulation i've updated it. The algorithm is correct. [1,5][2,3][7,10][6,8]  according to the algorithm the third iteration should be 
for [6,8] i've mistakenly done it [7,10].. because first we've to sort the intervals according to start time so [6,8] comes first. after third iteration- lastbound = max(5,8)= 8  and maxgap remains 0. after fourth iteration for [7,10] it would be lastbound 10 and maxgap will remain 0.

Answer (score 0):

We can have a simple, O(n) time O(1) space, algorithm to keep track of the interval we are in as we iterate over the intervals sorted by start position. The current interval starts with:

```
left = interval[0][0]
right = interval[0][1]
i = 1 // pointer
n = list length
max_gap = 0
```

Then,

```
while i < n and interval[i][0] <= right:
  // update right
  right = max(right, interval[i][1])
  i = i + 1
```

Now we are either at the end of the list if there were no gaps, or we are at a new interval that started at least at `(right + 1)` (which I think in your case wouldn't qualify as a gap).

So here update the current largest gap and repeat the while routine.

```
max_gap = max(
  max_gap,
  interval[i][0] - right - 1
)
left = interval[i][0]
right = interval[i][1]
```

JavaScript example:

```js
function f(A){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(A))
  let left = A[0][0]
  let right = A[0][1]
  console.log(`i: 0, (${ left }, ${ right })`)
  let i = 1 // pointer
  let n = A.length
  let max_gap = 0

  while (i < n){
    while (i < n && A[i][0] <= right){
      // update right
      right = Math.max(right, A[i][1])
      console.log(`i: ${ i }, (${ left }, ${ right })`)
      i = i + 1
    }

    if (i < n){
      max_gap = Math.max(
        max_gap,
        A[i][0] - right - 1
      )
      console.log(`i: ${ i }, max_gap: ${ max_gap }`)
      left = A[i][0]
      right = A[i][1]
    }
  }

  return max_gap
}

let examples = [
  [[1,5], [2,4], [6,10], [6,8]],
  [[1, 2], [2, 2], [5, 6], [8, 10]],
  [[2,4], [5,8], [9,10]],
  [[1,1], [5,6], [9,10]]
]

for (let ex of examples)
  console.log(`result: ${ f(ex) }\n\n`)
```

Comment: For the intervals [2,4],[5,8],[9,10] the output should be 1 not zero. As there is a gap at the start of the timeline, also you are not considering how many blocks are in the timeline, you are setting n to intervals length.

Comment: @sandrows your example in the question description, `[1, 2], [5, 6]...` states a gap of 2. That means a gap is defined by you to be `start - end - 1` (5 - 2 - 1 = 2). That seems to contradict your request for `[2,4],[5,8],[9,10]` to yield a gap of 1. Secondly, why are you bringing up the issue of what my code is setting `n` to? Could you please explain?

Comment: My example has two gaps, one of length 2 and another of length 1 (that is on the 7th block). I didn't say that a gap has to have a minimum number of blocks to be considered a gap, it could be of length 1 or 2 or more

Comment: Regarding the length of n... It cannot be simply set to the number of intervals, because you could, for example, have a timeline of 10 blocks with only one interval from [5,7]. Thus you have a gap of 4 blocks from the start of the timeline to the start of the interval and a gap of 3 from the end of the interval to the end of the timeline.

Comment: @sandrows regarding `[2,4],[5,8],[9,10] output should be 1` -- please resolve the conflict between your example, which shows `[1, 2], [5, 6]` as a gap of 2 and your request -- I don't see how the code could be made to have 2..5 represent a gap of 2 and at the same time have 4..5 or 8..9 represent a gap of 1. Regarding your description of the use of `n` -- I don't understand. Please give examples to help explain, and examples where the code fails and your expected output.